# How 剥がれたり works here?

Tags: grammar

I am bit puzzled by the use of 剥がれたり in the below panel

[image]

> 剥がれたりまばたきがしにくくなるから顔の筋肉に沿ってね

Why 剥ぐ is passive here? Also, what's the purpose of たり? It looks like a substitute for て form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously it should be originally 剥ぐ＋れる, but it is just a word on its own

> [はがれる](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%89%A5%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B/#je-60096)
> 〔とれる〕come off；〔皮をむくように〕peel off

[たり](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%9F%E3%82%8A/#je-46794) is a particle to list things. 読んだり書いたり means *read and write*. Strictly speaking, たり should come in pair, but the second たり is often dropped in modern usage (cf. [this](https://www.nhk.or.jp/bunken/summary/kotoba/gimon/154.html)), which is the case with the sentence of the question.

The sentence is 剝がれたりまばたきがしにくくなっ**たり**する, and means *(If you don't apply the tape properly) it comes off or makes it hard to blink..*.